# Android some much more Picasso features on Volly

Tags: android

after some googeling and read some best document about managment images on network. i'm try to use `Volley`. but `Picasso` has some very best features for image managment after download such as `resize`,`centerCrop` or create animation view on `onSuccess()` for example:

```
private void bindPhoto(final PhotoViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(photos.get(position))
            .resize(cellSize, cellSize)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.ivPhoto, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    animatePhoto(holder);
                }
                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
            });
}
private void animatePhoto(PhotoViewHolder viewHolder) {
    if (!lockedAnimations) {
        if (lastAnimatedItem == viewHolder.getPosition()) {
            setLockedAnimations(true);
        }
        long animationDelay = PHOTO_ANIMATION_DELAY + viewHolder.getPosition() * 30;
        viewHolder.flRoot.setScaleY(0);
        viewHolder.flRoot.setScaleX(0);
        viewHolder.flRoot.animate()
                .scaleY(1)
                .scaleX(1)
                .setDuration(200)
                .setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR)
                .setStartDelay(animationDelay)
                .start();
    }
}
```

now i can't find any document about use `Picasso` features with `Volley` or how to merge that with the `Volley`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), a comparable image loading library to Picasso that optionally uses [Volley integration](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Integration-Libraries#using-volley). A good comparison of the two APIs can be found in [this blog post](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en).

If you include Glide and the `volley-integration` library, then **every use of Glide will automatically use Volley** without any specific work on your part. Therefore you only need to worry about using Glide. In your case, the load would look similar to:

```
private void bindPhoto(final PhotoViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(context)
        .load(photos.get(position))
        // By default, Glide automatically resizes the image to fit
        // but you could .override(cellSize, cellSize)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(new ImageViewTarget<GlideDrawable>(yourViewObject) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(
                    GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation anim) {
                animatePhoto(holder);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: please read my topic again. i want to use picasso features with volley

Comment: Yeah Picasso doesn't have the extension points that would allow you to use Volley with it directly. If you want to use Volley, you should switch to Glide, which has a very similar API.

Comment: then how to integrate `Volley` with `Glide`

Comment: @mahdipishguy - did you see the link I posted on Volley integration? Including the `volley-integration` library and Volley is enough.

Comment: yes i see that sir. but i can find any document about how to use `Glide` methods on `Volley`, such as view image on `ImageView` or handle images after downloading by `Volley`. your introducing link is only help to integration  `Glide` with `Volley`

Comment: Did you read the comparison blog post I also linked? It details all of the Glide methods with the equivalent Picasso methods including viewing images in an `ImageView`, transforming the image, etc. Also consider reading the [Glide wiki](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki) which goes into [custom targets](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets#viewtarget)

Comment: yes i read it. can you update your topic by this quastion? how to use  `Glide` into `Volley` methods? download image with `Volley` and view downloaded image by `Glide`

Comment: Updated my answer with Glide code: if you include `volley-integration`, it is used automatically for you.